# Why/how are some organization members listed as collaborators on Github

Tags: github

I have a github repo that is part of an organization. I noticed today that some of the "Collaborators" are actually org members. How is this possible / why is this allowed?

IIUC all "collaborators" are "outside collaborators" (i.e. no such thing as a "inside collaborator"). So am I just wasting seats by setting org members as collaborators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your organization have a default policy (like org members have read only access to all repo of your org). Setting "collaborators" in a specific repository enable them to have another set of permission on this scecific repository (read /write access).

Usually, you manage your organization with "team" but is not mandatory. Adding one org member at a time on a repository is allowed (but not really efficient).

And no, you don't pay more if you set a member of your org as "collaborator" on a repo. You can check on the "members" and "outside collaborators" screen of your org. the account is only on one side or the other.

Comment: so "collaborator" is essentially "a team of one user, with custom permissions"